# Arrow Functions Lexical Scoping inside an Object

Tags: javascript, this

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#arrow_functions): "In arrow functions, `this` retains the value of the enclosing lexical context's `this`. In global code, it will be set to the global object"

If we have an object:

```
const object = {
  arrowFunc: () => this,
};
```

and then we call:

```
console.log(object.arrowFunc()); // Window {window: Window, self: Window, document: document, name: '', location: Location, …}
```

We get the window object, why is the arrow function not returning the object itself as `this`?

If the arrow function retains the `this` value of the enclosing lexical scope, then shouldn't that be the object where function itself is defined i.e `object`?

Comment: *If the arrow function retains the this value of the enclosing lexical scope, then isn't that the object itself where it's defined?* — No. It is the `this` value of the **function** where it is defined (or `window` if it is outside of any function). Object literals don't create a new lexical scope.

Comment: Can you please tell me why then if I instead use a regular function inside an object literal like `const object = {logThis() {console.log(this)}}}` it logs `object`?

Comment: That's the primary difference between arrow and other functions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work-and-when-should-it-be-used